# Unable to login user with OAuth2 using twitter-api-v2 typescript sdk in Next.js api

Tags: next.js, react-typescript, next.js13, twitter-api-v2

The sdk generates the url correctly and redirects user with no error where I store the codeVerifier and state. Error come when The callback is received and the stored codeverifier fails to authenticate the user with oauth2

```
export async function POST() {
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
const { url, state, codeVerifier, codeChallenge } = client.generateOAuth2AuthLink(
    CALLBACK_URL,
    {
        scope: [
            'tweet.read',
            'tweet.write',
            'tweet.moderate.write',
            'users.read',
            'follows.read',
            'follows.write',
            'offline.access'
        ]
    }
)

if (url && state && codeVerifier && codeChallenge) {

    await prisma.twitterCodeVerification.create({
        data: {
            state,
            codeVerifier,
            codeChallenge,
            userId: +session?.user?.id,
        },
    });

    return NextResponse.json({ url })
}
```

}

But when the callback is received and I successfully fetch the user's codeVerifier stored and pass them to loginWithOAuth2 I get Invalid verifier or access tokens

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {
const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url)
const sessionState = searchParams.get('state') as string
const code = searchParams.get('code') as string
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)

if (!sessionState && !code) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Missing state and code in request' }, { status: 400 })
}

if (!session) {
    redirect('/auth/login')
}

// Fetch the Twitter verification details (state, codeVerifier, codeChallenge) for the logged-in user
const verificationDetails = await prisma.twitterCodeVerification.findFirst({
    where: {
        userId: +session?.user?.id,
        state: sessionState
    },
});

if (!verificationDetails) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'No Twitter verification details found for the user' }, { status: 404 });
}

const codeVerifier = verificationDetails.codeVerifier as string;

const client = new TwitterApi({ clientId: CLIENT_ID, clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET })

client.loginWithOAuth2({ code, codeVerifier, redirectUri: CALLBACK_URL })
    .then(async ({ client: loggedClient, accessToken, refreshToken, expiresIn }) => {
        const TwitterToken = await prisma.twitterToken.create({
            data: {
                userId: +session?.user?.id,
                accessToken,
                refreshToken,
                expiresIn
            }
        })
        redirect('/profile/account')
    })
    .catch(() =>
        console.log('Invalid verifier or access tokens!')
    )
```

}